# JavaFX 8 - How to wrap text in new line in several controls?

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, textfield, javafx-8, word-wrap

I want to wrap text in a new line in some controls.
For example when there is not enough space to display the whole text of a checkbox, there should be a new line for that. I don't want these dots ("...").
The same behaviour I would like in a TableCell (not editable) and in a TextField or TextArea.

I tested `.setWrapText(true)` but this didn't help...

Can anybody help me please?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it depends on the layout you are using.

For example this code wraps the CheckBox text no problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckBoxTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("This is a really really really really really really really really long string");
        checkBox.setWrapText(true);
        pane.setCenter(checkBox);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

But if I were to change the BorderPane to a FlowPane, the wrapping would not work.

Comment: I'm using Checkboxes within an `TableView`... Do you have tips?